# PHP Angular - JWT Authorization Bearer Token

Tags: php, angular, http-headers, jwt

I am trying to get the authorization token being sent by angular to php. My angular intercepter looks as follows

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
        const clonedReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
        });
        return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
            tap(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status == 401){
                        localStorage.removeItem('token');
                        localStorage.removeItem('username');
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user/login');
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }
    else {
        return next.handle(req.clone());
    }
}
```

I console logged the request to see the output and it has the token.
[image]

Then i went to Network tab of developer tools to see if token was in the request and it was there.
[image]

Now how do I get the token in php? I tried following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582161/how-to-properly-use-bearer-tokens). But that doesn't help either. Following is the output when using the code in above answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi im speak spanish but i'm the same situation and I gonna tell u which way i took

searching for google and here I found u have to receive the JWT in $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] but this doesn't work at least in my shared host, I tried play whit the .htaccess file but nothing, you can check the details here [[Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM and Authorization headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018586/apache-2-4-php-fpm-and-authorization-headers]) also u can send the JWT through angular in JSON format to your php file, but i would recommend you to use HttpClientModule instead of HttpRequest if you want to send your data via GET or POST,

In PHP, this my test file, I sent the JWT in the URL this is not the best form to performance the tokens but in my case works, I hope  it helps.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$llave = 'TULLAVESECRETA';

$authHeader = $_GET['tok'];

try{
$decoded = JWT::decode($authHeader, $llave, array('HS256'));
        echo json_encode($decoded);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array(
        "mensaje" => "Vuelve a iniciar sesion.",
        "error" => $e->getMessage()
    ));
}

?>
```

I will edit if you comment

Comment: thank you. The .htaccess fix in the link you provided fixed the issue for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Include the following lines in the .htaccess file located on the api's folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Full answer here: [Authorization header missing in PHP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475885/authorization-header-missing-in-php-post-request)

Then you can read your "Bearer "+token with `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` or

```
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
$token = $requestHeaders["Authorization"];
```

You will still need to strip the "Bearer " text from `$token`.

```
if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches)) {
// alternately '/Bearer\s((.*)\.(.*)\.(.*))/' to separate each JWT string
    $stripped_token =  $matches[1];
}
```