# Failed to keep logged in angular when using php backend

Tags: php, angular, session-cookies, setcookie, http-authentication

I'm trying to make a login system on angular with a PhP backend.

**When people login**, this is the PhP script called :

```php
// here check for good request
$account = // found the account thanks to PDO
$accountId = $account["id"];
session_start();
$_SESSION["accountId"] = $accountId;
setcookie("accountId", $accountId, [
    'expires' => time() + 86400,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => false,
    'samesite' => 'None',
]);
```

Then, when I want to **get informations according to user**, I call this script :

```php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["accountId"]) && !isset($_COOKIE["accountId"])) {
    echo "You are not logged";
    die();
}
$accountId = isset($_SESSION["accountId"]) ? $_SESSION["accountId"] : $_COOKIE["accountId"];

// here get data
echo json_encode($accountId);
```

When I'm doing this in my browser, it works.

But when I'm doing it with angular, the `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` are empty, so it show me "*You are not logged*".

**My code in angular :**

```
this.http.get<T>("http://my-url.com/script.php").toPromise().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

**My question**:

How should I use PhP/Angular request to make secure login and data-request according to logged account? Should I change of language (to Java/C#/...)* (it's not a problem for me)?

**What I tried ?**

- Use `{ withCredentials: true }` on get method on angular:

```
this.http.get<T>("http://my-url.com/script.php", { withCredentials: true }).toPromise().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

I was getting a CORS error. After updating my header (see below), I get the same result: in browser it's fine but not in angular.

- I tried with `$_SESSION` and with `$_COOKIE`. Both are working in my browser, but not in angular.
- I think to put the `accountId` in the request, each time. But it's clearly not secure, and not a very good idea...
- Such as I had CORS issue, I add few lines to manage them:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
```

But, it solve all CORS issues but not my session/cookie empty.

So, how can I keep session and/or cookie in Angular, like my browser does?

Comment: I mean - fixing the CORS issue is fairly simple in PHP? Just read the request host and throw that in the CORS header? That is how it is usually done?

Comment: @MikeOne The PHP script isn't called, it's refused because of options request, so I edit apache config and now it's fine but some request are refused by apache and not by php

Comment: Also use a post request to login users. Don't change state (return a cookie, or modify the database) on a get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try vanilla-js function `fetch("url")` to deal with cookies and session storage.

But I advise you to use tokens for API requests rather than session storage or cookies. You'll have less problems and it's easier to upgrade later.

**For example**

Of course, you need to redesign your database, and your PHP code (as the JS one). When the user is logging in, to add a bit of security, you may need to hash the password with `md5()` or a better method like AES, as you like, and check if this hash correspond in the database. Then, respond with a success or an error followed by the user's token (created during sign up with PHP, generally a couple of `md5()` and `uniqid()`). This token must be long to avoid bruteforces.

Then, once the user is logged in and the Js code has the token, you have just to make API requests with this token.
More often, the token is provided in a header, `authorization: Bearer <token>` (replace "" by the token.) It's easy to use and easy to get in PHP. (Take a look at this question : [How to properly use Bearer tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582161/how-to-properly-use-bearer-tokens))

Comment: The fetch never return the content, even if http.get does. It's strange :/

Comment: You defenitely need to try the token's method.

Comment: I will do thanks. If any thing works i will be mad

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not about CORS. I had a similar situation on a php backend (CodeIgniter to be specific) and the problem was on the SameSite cookie attribute. Try to add this code inside a config file or index:

```
setcookie($name, $value, [
    'expires' => time() + 7200,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => 'domain.com',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => false,
    'samesite' => 'None',
]);
```

or for php >= 7.3:

```
 session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => time() + 7200,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => false,
    'samesite' => 'None'
]);
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750906/php-setcookie-samesite-strict) it might give you more hints.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it !

Comment: Update: I just upload it on real server with DNS. I update the "domain" value and then I tried. It's the same: It works with my browser but not with angular :/ (`$_COOKIE` is empty)

Comment: Update 2: I tried with "Lax" as SameSite value, I also tried with `ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Lax'); session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'Lax']);` but it always does the same: cookie field is empty

Comment: @Elikill58 be sure that **SameSite** value should be **none**, maybe there is some other configuration overriding those who are you are trying to setup. At least now you know your problems comes from the cookies. What is the version of your angular and php ?

Comment: Php I just upgrade to 7.3.5 to make this works. Angular i'm in 12.2.9. Also, I tried with None, Lax and Strict because i didn't find any quick explaination of what each value does

Comment: @Elikill58 can you check the answer again please I added something new for your version of php.

Comment: Ok, should I keep session_start() before the setcookie ?

Comment: @Elikill58 you should add the `session_set_cookie_params` function call on the config file if you have one , it has to be before `session_start` yes

Comment: That doesn't change anything, I have same issue. Do you want to go in PM (like in discord) to talk about it easier ?

Comment: I also update my question to edit details. I also tried lot of things specially by using CORS credentials & your answer at same time -> same result (cookie not saved)

Comment: @Elikill58 I am going to try and recreate the problem, can you also tell me the version of your apache ? and also what kind of browser are you using ? did you try another browser ?

Comment: Apache 2.4.39. I only try with chrome (latest version) but I tried in normal and incognito mode. Also, do you want virtualhost config or something ? Or go on discord to talk about it faster ?

Comment: I began with WAMP but I also tried with apache & php installed manually on ubuntu 18

Answer (score -1):

you must add cors headers in php script

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Comment: I already add first 2 line in Apache config (not the third). But i will try the last

Comment: @Elikill58 please add this file in top of php script file

Comment: In apache config or in php script directly I get "*blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*"

Comment: @Elikill58 are you test my code ??

Comment: @Elikill58 i update allow headers please test it

Comment: Ok, I will test. But yes, I c/c your code

Comment: I don't have CORS issue but the main issue is already here: the `$_SESSION` or cookie are not saved